# How to bootstrap a MariaDB cluster on CentOS 7?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, galera

I have consulted three guides to setting up a MariaDB cluster with Galera replication, but cannot get it bootstrapped.

I'm on CentOS 7 and have opted for installing MariaDB 10.1 from its official repository. The guides I've followed all differ slightly and none of their steps have worked for me.

I have consulted MariaDB's guide to [getting started with MariaDB Galera cluster](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/)

Issuing `galera_new_cluster` starts MariaDB on my first node. But starting the other nodes just starts them up normally. Querying `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';` shows a cluster size of `0` and status `Disconnected`.

I also consulted [Digital Oceans's guide for Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-ubuntu-12-04-servers) and get the same results.

As I'm on CentOS, I also checked [Linode's guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/host-a-website-with-high-availability#galera-with-xtradb) except it installs the Percona XtraDB package so the `mysql@bootstrap` command doesn't apply.

What is the correct procedure for starting up the cluster for the first time under CentOS 7 using Maria DB 10.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong path to the provider library.

```
#wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
```

Pointing to a file that doesn't exist wasn't raising any errors, so was just doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To start first Node on galera cluster called bootstrap that is below

service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster